# Why does the Tanakh translation have more verses in Numbers 27 than other translations do?

Tags: numbers, versification

In the Tanakh translation , Numbers chapter 27; has a lot more verses than other translations do. Why?

Example: Numbers 27:16-26 in the Tanakh, can not be found in the KJV Old Testament. The last verse is 13. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the KJV doesn't have these verses? https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+27&version=KJV

Comment: There are many versification schemes, I've been tracking the differences [here](https://github.com/curiousdannii/reversify/blob/master/src/transformations.data), but I don't know of any like you describe for Numbers.

Answer (score -1):

First, "Tanakh" is the Jewish name of the Old Testament. As such, it does not refer to a specific text. However, you are probably looking at a modern standard text, or a translation.

To answer your question, there are many different documents that record part or all of the Bible. Scholars take all these documents, some of which are in the original languages and some are translations, and they compare them meticulously. They compare the differences and strive to determine the original text. Sometimes, they can't reach a definite conclusion.

Most likely, the Tanakh version you are looking at is based on a specific text tradition. The KJV was based on limited texts as well compared to a modern text. Apparently, the Tanakh includes some verses that are not found only in some documents and that the KJV authors chose to exclude. This is not a matter of right and wrong, it is a matter of scholarly opinion and possibly tradition.

Comment: "Tanakh" is a common name for the [JPS translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Jewish_Publication_Society_of_America_Tanakh), I assume this is what the question is referring to.